# Docker Can't Find Response in Postman

Tags: c#, .net, docker, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm using a Docker Compose file to run two Docker Containers One an Image I already published and one a build. I can not see the image when I go to the configured location.

Docker Compose

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  twslogging:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}twslogging
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: twsLogging\Dockerfile
    ports:
      - '8000:8000'
  twsUsers:
    image: tbennet/twsusers
    ports:
      - '7000:7000'
```

DockerFile Loggin (One Built-in Docker compose Up)

```
#Depending on the operating system of the host machines(s) that will build or run the containers, the image specified in the FROM statement may need to be changed.
#For more information, please see https://aka.ms/containercompat

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.0-nanoserver-1803 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443
EXPOSE 8000

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.0-nanoserver-1803 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["twsLogging/twsLogging.csproj", "twsLogging/"]
RUN dotnet restore "twsLogging/twsLogging.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/twsLogging"
RUN dotnet build "twsLogging.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "twsLogging.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "twsLogging.dll"]
```

DockerFile (Users Docker file that is published)

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.0-nanoserver-1803 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443
EXPOSE 7000

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.0-nanoserver-1803 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY twsUsers/nuget.config ./
COPY ["twsUsers/twsUsers.csproj", "twsUsers/"]
COPY ["twsDatabase/twsDatabase.csproj", "twsDatabase/"]
COPY . .
RUN dotnet restore "twsUsers/twsUsers.csproj" --configfile ./nuget.config
WORKDIR "/src/twsUsers"
RUN dotnet build "twsUsers.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "twsUsers.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "twsUsers.dll"]
```

PostMan 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5nzWD.png)

Comment: What do you mean when you say you don't see the image at the configured location? Can you share the errors with us? Also, you shouldn't have both `image` and `build` for a single service. It should be one or the other. I assume you want to build `twslogging`.

Comment: twsLogging Works it's twsUsers that doesn't

Comment: What's your error? When I try to `docker pull` it appears to be a private registry.

Comment: I just added the picture. It is a private repository. In Postman I get Could not get any response

Comment: are you sure your application is running on port 7000 inside the container? You can test by logging into the running container and curl the same url that you try in postman (uses localhost and the same port so it should be fine). If you don't get any response inside the container either then double check the port where your application is running. note: exposing port 7000 in Dockerfile doesn't do a lot, it is more info for whoever uses the image.

Comment: When I do the Curl I get Unable to connect to the remote server. How do I find what port it is running on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the answer thanks for the comments they helped me look in the right spot. So For .net Core, this is what you do. on your port the port localhost number then 80 so I changed my port to 7000:80 and ran the compose and it came up. I found the answer looking here https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/blob/master/samples/run-aspnetcore-https-development.md